# exclude xml declaration while saving

Tags: linq-to-xml

i am generating an xml file using XDocument. when i save this file it adds

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

at the top of xml..

i want to exclude this before saving

how can i do that.

Comment: Why do you want to? Removing it should not affect any XML tool?

Comment: actually i am using SCSF framewokr for my application. it has ProfileCatalog.xml file and i am adding and removing plugins at runtime. after modification when i save this file it adds xml declaration at the top.

so when SCSF loads this xml file it gives me exception due to improper format. after mannually removing this top line it loads correctly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the save method to a XmlWriter http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336977.aspx, and creating this XmlWiter with XmlWriterSettings http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.settings.aspx

```
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;


XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(yourstream, settings);

yourXDocument.Save(writer);
```

Comment: I have seen some strange behavior regarding running this on a machine that has previously seen an assembly with the same name. A restart fixed it but it is unclear what was causing the problem.